# Mean per group on a bubble plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with a lot of overlapping points and used ggplot to create a bubble plot to show that data.  I need to add bars on my plot for the means of each group on the x axis (values can be 0, 1, or 2).  I have tried to use geom_errorbar but haven't been able to get it to work with my data.  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my code and a script to generate fake data that is similar:

```
y <- seq(from=0, to=3.5, by=0.5)
x <- seq(from=0, to=2, by=1)
xnew <- sample(x, 100, replace=T)
ynew <- sample(y, 100, replace=T)
data <- data.frame(xnew,ynew)

data2 <- aggregate(data$xnew, by=list(x=data$xnew, y=data$ynew), length)
names(data2)[3] <- "Count"

ggplot(data2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size=Count)) + 
    labs(x = "Copies", y = "Score") + 
    aes(ymax=..y.., ymin=..y..) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2, 1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3, 0.5)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal", 
    axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size = 10), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size = 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? I first calculated the group-level means using the `dplyr` package and then added line segments to your plot using `geom_segment`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data2 %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(mean.y = mean(y))
ggplot(data2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_point(aes(size=Count)) + 
labs(x = "Copies", y = "Score") + 
aes(ymax=..y.., ymin=..y..) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2, 1)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3, 0.5)) + 
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal", 
    axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size = 10), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size = 10)) +
geom_segment(aes(y = mean.y, yend = mean.y, x = x -0.25, xend = x + 0.25))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do.  I just had to add back in the part of my code where the count object was created.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure that I understand your question correctly. It seems to me that in addition to the bubbles, you want to visualise the mean value of `y` for each value of `x` as a bar of some kind. (You mention error bars, but it seems that this is not a requirement, but just what you have tried. I will use `geom_col()` instead.)

I assume that you want to weigh the mean over `y` by the counts, i.e., `sum(y * Count) / sum(Count)`. You can create a data frame that contains these values by using `dplyr`:

```
data2_mean
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##       x        y
##   <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1     0 1.833333
## 2     1 1.750000
## 3     2 2.200000
```

When creating the plot, I use `data2` as the data set for `geom_point()` and `data2_mean` as the data set for `geom_col()`. It is important to put the bars first, since the bubbles should be on top of the bars.

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_col(aes(x = x, y = y), data2_mean, fill = "gray60", width = 0.7) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, size = Count), data2) + 
    labs(x = "Copies", y = "Score") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2, 1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3, 0.5)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal", 
    axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size = 10), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size = 10))
```

Everything that I changed compared to your code comes before `scale_x_continuous()`. This produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: That wasn't quite what I was looking for.  I needed a much thinner bar at the mean.  Thank you for your input, though.  I appreciate the suggestion.